# How to format date by regions?

Tags: angular, date, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using ionic 2 with angular2. I'm trying to format date automatically for each country or language.

I format the date so:

```
{{dateVariable | date: 'dd/MM/y HH:mm'}}
```

But in the France the format is:

`dd/mm/yyyy`

in the Switzerland:

`dd.mm.yyyy`

In the US:

`m/d/yyyy`

And so for lot of countries.

How can I format automatically the date corresponding with the correct country or language?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geofence/

Comment: Have you considered using an unambiguous format like d MMM, yyyy e.g. 23 May, 2017?